# basic php regex question

Tags: php, regex

I have an html file where I'd like to get all the text inside these two tags:

```
<div class="articleTitle">
</div>
```

I'm not entirely sure how to do the php regex.
(I also know there are no html tags inside the div, so there's no problem about nested tags)

update: when i try the solutions given i get this: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'd' on line 29

Comment: If you explicitly require a match between the <div> tags, change (.*?) for (.+?) as this will require 1+ matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_match('/<div class="articleTitle">(.*?)<\/div>/i', $source, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

This is the "Explination" from RegexBuddy:

```
<div class="articleTitle">(.*?)</div>

Options: case insensitive

Match the characters “<div class="articleTitle">” literally «<div class="articleTitle">»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the characters “</div>” literally «</div>»

Created with RegexBuddy
```

(.*?) will capture everything between what comes before it until what comes after it, and it will be places into the $matches var.

I assumed that the HTML will be in the $source var.

I suggest that you look into [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/), it's 39.95 (USD) but it is worth every penny.  It can help build your RegExs with most every major RegEx implementation, and it can help you to learn RegEx

Comment: Just fixed my preg_match I was missing the /s and the case-insensitive flag.

Comment: when i try that i get this:
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'd' on line 29

Comment: Escape the forward slash in '</div>', so rather write '<\/div>'.

Comment: Thanks Torok I didn't the code so that slipped by, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 2):

Wrong answers!

```
preg_match('#<div\s+[^>]*class="articleTitle"[^>]*>(.*)</\s*div>#ims', $str, $matches);
```

1. DIV can be empty, so pattrns like (.+) are wrong.
2. you shold use "m" modifier - content can be multiline.
3. you should use "s" modifier to match dot-metacharacter as newline.
4. Just wonder, why escape slash if pattens in php can have ANY delimiter? Usually I use # as delimiter in this case.
5. DIV can have additional attributes and/or space characters (including newlines).

Sorry, have no time to test pattern good, but it seems to be correct. This should work in any case.

PS: and, GONeale, about greediness - pattern must be greedy and it IS greedy without modifier "U".

Comment: Had a look at patterns again and noticed that (.+?) must work, but why using 2 quantifiers when they are in summary equal to "*" ? Or I don't know something and they work different ways...?

PS: thanks, GONeale, but why challenger?

Answer (score 0):

This would be more correct, as other solutions would match <div class="articleTitle"><div/> by itself, which is probably undesirable?

```
preg_match('<div class="articleTitle">(.+?)</div>', $test_string, $matches);
```

Comment: this will only capture 1 character and, if there is more then one (even whitespace) will cause it to not match, as-well it will not be captured.

Comment: That expression does not capture but match the text inside. And since it's greedy, it may match the wrong closing tag.

Comment: @raj no, as I said in my comment this will only capture a single character and there must not be any other characters in the text.

Comment: I was going to ask if there was a necessity to make it greedy or not.

Comment: @Unkwntech actually, it will match 0 to unlimited characters, which is probably wrong anyway.  We both should be using '.+?'

Answer (score 0):

```
'/<div class="articleTitle">(.*?)<\/div>/'
```

Would generally work; however, if you need to take into account other possible attributes in the div tag, it would be a little more complex.

Comment: That expression does not capture but only matches the text inside.

Comment: Yes, I missed that - add the () to match. I was just trying to give the basic idea, there are other far better (and a little harder to parse) examples in the answers.