# What do these regex Patterns Match?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am new to regex in PHP and understand the basic patterns however the ones below are a bit complex and I don't understand what the following pattern matches:

```
$ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#... "<a href='' rel='nofollow'></a>", $ret);

$ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*... "<a href='http://' rel='nofollow'></a>", $ret);
```

Could someone please explain them?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the whole expressions not only half of them.

Comment: FYI, PCRE is the regex library that powers PHP's preg_ functions.  I removed that tag because there's nothing specific to that library in your question.

Comment: @Alan M: Edited contrary because it's Perl Compatible Regular Expressions which are specifically being asked about, not any of the other flavors of regex available in PHP.  (If we truly ever need a tag that's about the PCRE library as such, we can use pcre-lib.)

Comment: How about "preg" or "preg_replace" then? In most contexts, "pcre" is either ambiguous or redundant IMO. But "pcre-lib" sounds good for questions about using the library directly. We do see questions about that once in a blue moon. :)

Answer (score 3):

In short: Replace URLs by links.

In detail:

1. The first regex describes sequences that begin with word characters (`[\w]+`), followed by `://`, followed by one or more characters of the set `[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]`.

   That should probably match a URL beginning with the URL protocol/scheme like `http://`, `https://` or `ftp://`.

   But it would also match `javascript://`. And that’s not good: `javascript://%0Aalert%28%22booo%21%22%29` equals the JavaScript code:

   ```
   //
   alert("booo!")
   ```
2. The second regex describes sequences that begin with either `www.` or `ftp.`, again followed by one or more characters of the set `[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]`.

   That should probably match URLs, that just begin with `www.` or `ftp.`. The URL protocol/scheme is then added to the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Get [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/), and it explains you ([see screenshots](http://www.regexbuddy.com/screen.html)) what any regular expression means. There is another [anwser here in SO that demonstrates that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891477/basic-php-regex-question/891487#891487).

Anyway, according to the second arguments of the `preg_replace`s, they should match URLs and tagify them.